# PayPal, Serve, Google Wallet ... URLs to ask a payment

Tags: paypal, payment

This is not exactly a development question, but I hope somebody can help, or point me in right direction.

I'm developing a small Android app. One of its features will be to allow users to share links to ask others a payment. For example, if user want to ask another person to pay him for something using PayPal, he can enter his PayPal email, subject, currency and amount, and the app will generate a URL like this one (and optionally shorten it, give stats, a few other features):

```
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=<email>&item_name=<description>&amount=<amount>&currency_code=<currency>
```

I have tested that and it's working OK with PayPal.

I'd also like to include other payment services like Serve.com, GoogleWallet, IngDirect, AmazonPayments, WePay, Allpay and others.

I'm having problems finding equivalent URL to easily pass all parameters to start a payment: each service's equivalent URL to mentioned PayPal's one.

I'm not in the U.S. so I can't even create an account in serve.com and others.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You won't realistically be able to offer any services for which you cannot obtain an account for yourself. With serve.com, can you not sign up for a developer account (I've no idea myself, not heard of them)?

Comment: Is information on the others hard to come by? I'd find it difficult to believe that, say, GoogleWallet, doesn't have good support docs available.